# MongoDb Collection.find() with multiple operators on query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I need to collect elements of a collection of MongoDb using two parameters within a array of an object.

I using `collectionX.find` type () to bring only those elements that have the combination of "services.servicesId: `[" 1 "," 3 "," 6 "]` with `"services.value": true`, without `"services.value" : false`

Always returns all elements because all elements has the "servicesId" .

I tried several ways, including using the $ sign, but without success, returned an empty array. I tried with `$and` and returns all elements too.

I am using this code to Publish on Meteor Client:

```
 var servicesIds = ["1", "3", "5"]
    return CollectionX.find (
        {"services.serviceId": {$in: servicesIds}},
        {"services.value": true}
    );
```

The object has the following structure:

```
Id: "ou5HNQGM2KxbBetmy"
createdAt: Mon Apr 06 2015
otherData: Object
personalData: Object
email: test@gmail.com
mobilephone: "11-98654-8785"
name: "UserName"
phone: "11-2625-6364"
services: Array [20]
0: Object {
serviceId: "1",
value: true
} ...
```

Comment: what you get with this. ? `CollectionX.find({'services.serviceId' : { $in: [servicesIds] }}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always returns all elements because all elements has the `servicesId`

Thats because you are setting the `"Services.value": true`, away from the array, so the query is ignoring it, try to separate it just by a `,` and not as a different query parameter like you have using an `{}`

Try with [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

```
   var servicesIds = ["1", "3", "5"]
    CollectionX.find( { services: 
         { $elemMatch : { 'Services.serviceId' : servicesIds, "Services.value" : true } } } );
```

Comment: I tried this:   return BrideRequests.find(
            {'services.serviceId' : { $in: servicesIds },
            "services.value": false}); 

And return all elements too.

Comment: Its a punctuation error . I fixed, but does not bring the result I want , combining the two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your second search parameter is applied as projection. Try:

```
  var servicesIds = ["1", "3", "5"]
  return CollectionX.find (
       {"Services.serviceId": {$ in: servicesIds},
        "Services.value": true}  // moved { }
  );
```

Comment: if I put "services.value: false" I have the same result, returning the elements with "services.value: true" too.

Comment: Note that if one of the elements in array `services` matches, then the whole element, with whole array will be returned. You might be looking for `$elemMatch` operator.

Comment: Worked! Thanks!
The line-code:  

services: {$elemMatch: {serviceId : {$in : servicesIds}, value: true}}